# In Canada, are there consequences if an airline provides a false reason for a delay?

Tags: air-travel, canada

If an airline issues an alert to its passengers saying that the delay is due to "weather", but those passengers are on the plane and the air crew explained it was actually due to an error in the plane's manifest, can the airline face consequences?

Comment: Do you want to know if they face any penalty for such alert messages in itself, or are you more interested in the case where they use "weather" as an excuse to deny passengers their legally entitled compensation?

Comment: Did that notification have any effect on the passengers?

Comment: Why are you asking? Legal "consequences" are mostly academic and irrelevant unless someone actually takes a legal action which seems unlikely in this case.  What specifically is your goal?

Comment: My goal is to explore options. I do not trust the airline will deliver on its compensation claims since they are officially blaming weather even though it wasn't. We do have a complaints offices in Canada so I figured I'd explore what options there are